# How can I add CSRF token to upload file using HTML 5 (data-) inside an input?

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf, csrf

I'm using this  [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) plugin to upload file in my WebApp.
To develop this WebApp I'm using: `Bootstrap4`, `Thymeleaf` and `Spring Boot`.

I would like to use the html5 convenction to use that plugin, so this is the code:

```
<div class="file-loading" >
    <input id="uploadPDF" type="file" class="file" data-theme="fas" data-allowed-file-extensions='["pdf"]' 
    data-language="it" data-type="POST" th:data-upload-url="@{/path/{id}/pdf(id=${myObject.id})}"/>
</div>
```

But I enabled the CSRF protection with Spring Security. So when I try to upload a pdf the result is:

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

I would like to add the CSRF token using the HTML5 convection, so something like:

`<input .... data-toke="token"...>`

In this way I can avoid to use the javascript. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the csrf token with `${_csrf.token}`.  So:

```
<input ... th:data-token="${_csrf.token}" ... />
```

Comment: Nothing change.. The response is always: `status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.","path":"/path/1/pdf"` but in the source page the value is not null